# Handle Python pickle bytes object in C#

Tags: c#, python.net

Using Pythonnet in a C# application:

Python returns a `bytes ({<class 'bytes'>})` object which is the result of a `pickle.dumps` operation.

What is the best way of dealing with this object in C# in terms of persistance to blob storage and rehydrating a `bytes` object to pass back to Python at a later stage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Assuming you have access to the Python side of the equation**, the easiest way to deal with these sorts of problem is to serialize the object in some sort of mutually understood format.

In this case, one idea would be to **serialize the bytes into base64** (unicode such as UTF-8 or -16 can run into encoding issues depending on the contents of the byte string). Then you could **convert that base64 bytes into UTF-8** to communicate it back across programs.

This looks like (for example):

```
base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps("Some data goes here")).decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: While this way works well it is not most efficient. There must be a more direct way to copy the bytes directly into a C# byte[].

Comment: Sure, tons of optimizations are possible. You could always stream bytes through a socket or pass along a (memory address, data length) pair for example.

However, I doubt this will be the bottleneck of most programs. I'd make sure it actually is a bottleneck before bothering with a more complicated approach.